# Linux Terminal Color Design overlapping

Tags: linux, terminal

I've shorten and add background and foreground color with this code:

```
PS1='\e[42;1m\u:\e[44m\W\$ \e[0m '
```

But it overlapping instead of go to next line like this:

[image]

Before overlapping:
[image]

Comment: Use `export PS1='\[\033[01;42m\]\u:\[\033[01;44m\]\W\$ \[\033[00m\] '`

Comment: Wow man! Thanks, Ok I've another question, If I have activated any virtual environment, it shows like this:
`(versity_project) mohib@mohib-pc:~/MEGA/Django/versity_project/bookmarks$ 
`
Now can I indicate anyhow the (versity_project) ?
And how can I save it permanently ?

Comment: I don't get the question? what's the problem virtualenv?

Comment: There is no any problem, In shorten form I just want to add "(versity_project)" or whatever my virtualenv folder name! Thanks

Comment: imo virtualenv should do this by default, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `\[` and `\]` bits which mark the beginning and the end of not-displayable characters. Use this:

```
export PS1='\[\e[01;42m\]\u:\[\e[01;44m\]\W\$ \[\e[00m\] '
```